# Access XML file from another server and store data to my database

Tags: xml, postgresql, jsp, server, remote-access

Suppose an xml file is stored in another server.

```
www.example.com/test.xml
```

now i want to load that xml file`s data in my postgres database using jsp.
how to do that. plzz help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following Java code inside a servlet (if you have one) or inside your jsp file (inside a scriptlet) but that would make for a terrible design

```
 public String getXmlFromUrl(String url)    {


    BufferedReader reader = null;
    StringBuilder stringBuilder=null;
    String lineSeparator = System.getProperty("line.separator");

    try{
        URL url = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/xml");
        conn.setReadTimeout(10000);//set timeout to 10000 or whatever you think is OK
        conn.connect();
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(),"UTF-8"));
        stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String line=null;
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
            stringBuilder.append(line + lineSeparator);
        }


    catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        if(reader!=null)
            try {
                reader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
    return stringBuilder.toString();
}
```

For inserting the xml into your database, use JDBC. If you don't Know how to do that , just Search SO, there's plenty of examples.